# \includepdf is including a page before the titlepage

Tags: titles, pdfpages

I am working on a document where the second page is an scanned page, so I am using `\includepdf` to add it.

The basic document looks like:

```
\begin{titlepage}
.
.
.
\end{titlepage}

\includepdf[noautoscale]{file.pdf}
```

The problem I have is that the inserted page appears before the titlepage once rendered. I have had this issue in other less important documents and I just added the page afterwards with other software, but it breaks the links. Any ideas of why this is happening and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Maybe try a `\newpage` in front of the `\includepdf[noautoscale]{file.pdf}`? If this does not help, can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: `\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\title{MWE}
\author{pepito }
\date{August 2017}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\includepdf{statement2.pdf}



\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}`

This MWE appears to be working, will try to figure out something else

Answer (score 1):

I just managed to fix it by adding packages one by one. The issue was the afterpage package. Removing this package and the one command that required it fixed the issue and I can't notice any difference in the document.

I was using it because the template used it.

Comment: Ah, templates!  Bad practices turned into tradition.